# AndroidStudio won't highlight outdate library after switch to use Kotlin DSL

Tags: android, kotlin

### Previously Android studio will automatically highlight outdated libraries like this:

[image]

### After I changed to use full kotlin property instead to declare dependency like this:

[image]

### Then IDE won't highlight it anymore.

[image]

- I tried several ways to declare the dependency but seems if use Kotlin property instead of hardcode the dependency's name then IDE won't highlight if library outdated.
- Q: Is there a way to highlight outdated libraries and also using the new way(declare dependency as property) to declare dependency?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 7):

Android Studio doesn't currently support dependency update suggestions with Gradle Kotlin DSL.

You need to use a plugin to check for dependency updates like this one: https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin

Add this plugin in your project-level `build.gradle.kts` file:

```
plugins {
    id("com.github.ben-manes.versions") version "0.28.0"
}
```

And then simply run `./gradlew dependencyUpdates` to check for dependency updates.

Comment: Good library. But seems it will only show the dependency version info in terminal or html. That is not intuitive like previous AS directly highlight in Gradle file :(

Comment: And it takes minutes to get the results with gradle-versions-plugin